# List of strings stored as values in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, localization, automated-tests

I have a testing framework that needs to be updated to include testing in Spanish. I have a CSV file that contains the field label, english text, and Spanish text. I've decided to use a dictionary to store the field label as the key and the values would be a list of strings for Spanish and English text.

```
   private List<string> ReadTranslationCsv()
    {
        var pathToCSV = @"C:\Location";
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> translations = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        string label, englishText, spanishText;
        using (TextReader fileReader = File.OpenText(pathToCSV))
        {
            var csv = new CsvReader(fileReader);
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;

            while (csv.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; csv.TryGetField<string>(i, out label);)
                {
                    List<string> Spanglish = new List<string>();

                    csv.TryGetField<string>(i + 1, out englishText);
                    Spanglish.Add(englishText);
                    csv.TryGetField<string>(i + 2, out spanishText);
                    Spanglish.Add(spanishText);

                    if (label != "")
                    {
                        translations.Add(label, Spanglish);
                    }   

                    i = i + 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to search within the list of values to see if anything matches some string of text. I'm not sure how to search the lists that are within the dictionary, none of the default methods or properties are working.

I'm using the below code but this will return me a bool, which is not what I need, I need the list value that matches the elementWithText

```
    public void GivenElementMatches(string elementWithText)
            {
                if (Config.Language == "Spanish")
                {
                    var list = new List<string> { elementWithText };//must create list in order to pass text to any translations methods
                    Hooks.translations.ContainsValue(list); // Even though the labels are the key, I need to search for the english text which is index 1 of the list and all values should be returned

                }
//TODO
}
```

Comment: What's the question here? What issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: I can't use any of the methods or properties within the dictionary easily if I'm trying to search for a value within the lists.

Comment: You need to also share the code which is having issue. The current code is all about reading file and creating dictionary.

Comment: Where in this code do you have a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>`?

Comment: Welcome to SO syso.  I am not sure but I think you are asking us how to search the object referenced by the variable `translations`, whose declaration you have not posted and whose type is not discernable from the example.  Those seem important ;) Please post a [mcve] so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a Dictionary with a class you create, inside that class you can have a compare function.

The advantage of this method is you may add more language equivalents later and only have to change your model.

Please note, this code is not complete and you will have to bug check and alter it to suit.

```
Dictionary <string, LangEquivalents> model;

public KeyValuePair<string, LangEquivalents> findField(string input) 
{
    return model.First(x=>x.Value.Comparison(input));
}
```

You could also make it a comparable object type and just use `model.First(x=>x.Value == input));`